# Como integrar jquery-ui com react?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, react, jquery-ui

Estou com dúvida... gostaria de integrar o jquery-ui com react... estou criando uma calculadora e não sei como fazer para que ela se mova sobre a tela.

Estou tentando colaborar com software livre e não sei muito...

Peguei esse código oficial da documentação

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <style>
            #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
        </style>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#draggable").draggable();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
            <p>Drag me around</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable();
});
</script>
```

A calculadora é

https://codepen.io/fabiozinid/pen/BoOGPN

Links

https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

https://reactjs.org/

Comment: A pergunta certa é por que integrar jQuery com React? Ainda mais se for apenas por causa de 1 animação

Comment: como o @Costamilam comentou, deveria pensar melhor sobre usar os dois, você sabe exatamente o que ambos fazem? assim está só "costurando" seu código, juntando partes, seria mais simples procurar um plugin que faça o *drag and drop* para react sem precisar de jquery